# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty :import model

Tags: django, django-models

CODE:
https://github.com/Strzelba2/STOCK/blob/main/STOCK/WIG/WIG_scrap.py

When i try import my model to `WIG_scrap.py`

```py
from .models import CompanyData , Quotes
```

I get the error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty
```

but without importing the model, everything works fine.

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening

Comment: you specify a non-empty `SECRET_KEY = '...'` in `settings.py`.

Comment: yes,  when i remove  import ,everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECRET_KEY

> The secret key is used for:
>
> - All sessions if you are using any other session backend than django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache, or are using the default get_session_auth_hash().
> - All messages if you are using CookieStorage or FallbackStorage.
> - All PasswordResetView tokens.
> - Any usage of cryptographic signing, unless a different key is provided.

So... without using DB and models you don't need to provide Secret_Key. Unless you won't use sessions etc.

Just set your SECRET_KEY string in settings.